# How to change data of some parameters in a Json with swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, api

I am working on a project which it is reading a json from an API which it provides currency of different countries  and the output is like this.

```
{
base = EUR;
date = "2019-08-03";
rates =     {
AED = "4.08777";
AFN = "89.092349";
ALL = "121.761514";
AMD = "529.6588400000001";
ANG = "1.985008";
AOA = "391.621548";
ARS = "49.530913";
AUD = "1.636268";
AWG = "2.003316";
AZN = "1.897631";
BAM = "1.960138";
BBD = "2.245272";
BDT = "94.033858";
BGN = "1.960138";
BHD = "0.419517";
        .
        .
        .
     };
    success = 1;
    timestamp = 1564832346;
   }
```

as you see the base is EUR which stands for euro, I want to change the base to USD.

here is my codes:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self

    //Getting data

    print("Hello Wrold")
    let url = URL(string: "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=")
    print(url!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        print("Hello Wrold3")
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Hello Wrold2")
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    print(myJson)

                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()




}
```

I tried to reach it by writing myJson.base but seems it does not understand it. 
Does any one have any idea how to do it? Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't post your API key on a public forum. But to answer your question, you're going to need to look at the [documentation](https://fixer.io/documentation). Hint: Look for "Changing base currency"

Comment: You can easily use any currency as your base currency with your current data. You just need to convert twice, from some currency to EUR and then from EUR to USD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with JSON, but how to [tell the api to use a different base currency](https://fixer.io/documentation#basecurrency).

```
https://data.fixer.io/api/latest
    ? access_key = API_KEY
    & base = USD
```

---

but checking with your key, I receive this

> ```
> {"success":false,"error":{"code":105,"type":"base_currency_access_restricted"}}
> ```

with this explanation for the [error code](https://fixer.io/documentation#errors)

> 105   The current subscription plan does not support this API endpoint.

Comment: Thank you. You mean I should change this line right ? `let url = URL(string: "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=...&base=USD")` it face an error base_currency_access_restricted

Comment: I am still coding. its a student project . then you mean I am doing right and the problem is just purchasing right?

Comment: check this one, Your error tells that you are using a free service https://github.com/fixerAPI/fixer/issues/109

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't post your API key in public.
2. This isn't a Swift question, but more of a API question. Look at the [documentation](https://fixer.io/documentation). Hint: Look for "Changing base currency"